# XML's not being resolved/recognized by Eclipse?

Tags: android

I've just done a fresh re-install/extract of Eclipse off Android's website, hardly added much code or XML to my project, yet nothing's being recognized outside of my MainActivity.java. And before you ask-yes, I've tried cleaning and restarting Eclipse.

(see comments for where the errors are) For example, in the first method (onCreate), the second like there's activity_main that Eclipse is saying it can't resolve, as if it doesn't exist. Consequently, my CreateLG button in the onCreateLGClick method isn't resolved/recognized either. Neither is the main (.xml) or createlg_menu (.xml) resolved..

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.groceryrunner;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // not resolved or isn't a field
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); // main isn't recognized
        return true;
    }


    public void onCreateLGClick(View v) {
        final int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
        case R.id.CreateLG: // CreateLG button from activity_main isn't recognized either
            //findViewById(R.id.GetStarted).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            createLGPopup(v);
            break;
        /*case R.id.ListsButton:
            findViewById(R.id.GetStarted).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            createLGMenu(v);
            break;*/
        }
    }

    public void createLGPopup(View v) {
        PopupMenu LGMenu = new PopupMenu(this, v); // createlg_menu isn't recognized as well
        LGMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.createlg_menu, LGMenu.getMenu());
        LGMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                String choice = new String((String) item.getTitle());
                if (choice == "Create_List") {
                    //createListDialog();
                }
                else if (choice == "Create_Group") {
                    //createListDialog();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        LGMenu.show();
    }

}
```

Here's the other files:

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/CreateLG"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

createlg_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/createList" android:title="Create List"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/createGroup" android:title="Create Group"></item>    

</menu>
```

main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: If R.java isn't generating, nothing will resolve when you make references to it.  Anytime that happened to me, it was either a build issue or something in the XML that stopped Android from generating R.java.

Comment: Hmm.. okay, I've tried moving my Gen folder out so that Eclipse had to generate it again (along with R.java), but that didn't help (I put the original Gen folder back).

Comment: Are there any errors in any of the XML files?  When you look at the project p, does it have any errors\?

Comment: Nope, the only errors are the ones in the MainActivity.java file regarding the unrecognized file names.

Comment: I've also noticed that R doesn't say the right class I believe (com.example.groceryrunner.R ), see the following image: http://i.imgur.com/IWvGoRq.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i encounter this issue, the first step is to remove the import android.R line. That is the wrong R.

Next, comment out any line referencing R and build the project. That will make new gen folder with the R values.

Most likely your issue is importing android.R so the app looks in there instead of in your R gen file. But Eclipse gets silly sometimes and won't build without commenting those out, so try both steps to be sure.

Comment: MOTHERS OF NEPTUNE'S PEARLS you've done it!!! I deleted the import, commented out the lines, restarted Eclipse, Built All, and wa-la!! They're all recognized now! Only took 2 days to fix this error... thank you, sir!

Comment: Glad i could help. I can tell you i have stared at this problem for days the first time it happened. Eclipse can be strange sometimes.