# My R.id.<name> wont resolve

Tags: android, eclipse, android-resources

My question is similar to the one linked below.
[XML's not being resolved/recognized by Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345086/xmls-not-being-resolved-recognized-by-eclipse)

I am writing code trying to use R.id. but it wont find the id's that I used.

```js
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/contactlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

```js
    private class ContactListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact>{
        public ContactListAdapter() {
            super (MainActivity.this, R.layout.contactlayout, Contact); <!--wont find contactlayout-->
```

I tried to remove the "import android.R;", comment out the R lines, and build it again. The link doesn't say where to import the R from so when I do the problem comes back. Thanks for your help.

PS if I didn't do this post right please let me know. It is my first.

Comment: When you hover you mouse on the red underlined R, what are the suggestions? Isn't your R file in one of the suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any error in your layout files? Any red marker?

Comment: It says it can't be resolved. How do I find my R file in my project so I can import the right one?

Comment: @joao2fast4u Yes I do have errors on my activity_main but they are mostly the R problems.

Comment: What is your project package name? You have to import your.full.project.name.R;

Comment: I mean, in any of your res folder files has a red marker on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project's `R` will be generated in a Java package with the same name as the Android package name in your manifest.  So if the Android package name is `com.example.myproject`, classes that are not in the Java package `com.example.myproject` need to `import com.example.myproject.R;`.

Note that your project's Android package name does not necessarily correspond to any Java package in your project.  They just usually correspond because they both follow the same naming conventions.

Comment: That makes sense but it is saying it can't be resolved. How do I find my R file. I have goggled it many times but the best I could come up with is that it refers to the res folder in my project. Is this the case?

Comment: @Hausfer If `R` isn't where it's supposed to be, it's probably not being generated because of some error in your XML.  If you're using Eclipse, clean and rebuild the project and then look for the little red icons in the package explorer.

Answer (score 0):

It won't compile because R.layout class refers to the names of the XML files and not the parent Views inside the files. So it would be

```
private class ContactListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact>{
        public ContactListAdapter() {
            super (MainActivity.this, R.layout.nameofthexmlfile, Contact);
```

Comment: Thanks I think I understand what you are saying. The R.layout.<name> is of the name of the xml file under layout not the id in that layout. I will take that into account but the problem is that even with the right name it still wont resolve. @KevinKrumwiede from the comment above notes that I need to import my R file not androids one but I do not know how to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help. It turned out to be one of my layouts had errors that were causing the problem and I had imported android.R when I should have imported com.someName.MyApp.R. I also found my R.java file, its under gen/myapp. Hope this helps someone else. Thanks again.